How to get a list of privileges for a postgresql database?
I grant different database access privileges to different users.
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbname TO user1

How can I get a list of granted privileges to this database for all users?
In the pgAdmin application, in the database settings, there is a security tab where all these privileges are specified. How can I get the same data with an SQL query?

P.S. Welcome to stackoverflow.com, but you are requested to do some research before asking a question (see: How to ask)
